# Trying to make a simple Long Polling chat with Node.js and Mongodb

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, mongodb, express

Basically I have a collection **db.test.message** that only has the field **_id** and **text**

The client sends the number of messages it has printed to the server (first 0), if **db.test.messages.count()** is greater than this number it sends only the new messages (or documents), if it's not, then the server waits till new messages are created. It repeats this operation over and over.

At first all messages are printed correctly, but I get an error on the second request (localhost:3000/messages?num_of_messages=3)

```
Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.
at ServerResponse.OutgoingMessage.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:335:11)
at ServerResponse.writeHead (_http_server.js:195:21)
at c:\nodejs\myapp\app.js:41:30
at handleCallback (c:\nodejs\node_modules\mongodb\lib\utils.js:95:12)
at c:\nodejs\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cursor.js:590:16
at handleCallback (c:\nodejs\node_modules\mongodb\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\cursor.js:234:5)
at setCursorDeadAndNotified (c:\nodejs\node_modules\mongodb\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\cursor.js:424:3)
at nextFunction (c:\nodejs\node_modules\mongodb\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\cursor.js:586:7)
at Cursor.next (c:\nodejs\node_modules\mongodb\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\cursor.js:614:3)
at fetchDocs (c:\nodejs\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cursor.js:586:10)
```

I used this example and changed it to my needs:
http://www.stoimen.com/blog/2010/12/02/diving-into-node-js-a-long-polling-example/

I know I'm trying to write on **response.wirte** after using **response.end()** but according to the example above and my code there's no way that could happen unless there some asynchronous execution happening that I'm not aware of.

Here's the client side code:

```
$(function () {
            $('#ready').append('ready');

            function check_for_new_messages(num_of_messages) {
                $.ajax({
                    cache: false,
                    // setup the server address
                    url: '/messages?num_of_messages=' + num_of_messages,
                    data: {},
                    success: function (response, code, xhr) {

                        if (response.no_new_messages) {
                            check_for_new_messages(num_of_messages);
                            return false;
                        }

                        // do whatever you want with the response
                        var msgs = response;
                        for (var i = 0; i < msgs.length; i++) {
                            $('#messages').append(msgs[i]._id + ',' + msgs[i].text + '<br/>');
                        }
                        // make new call
                        check_for_new_messages(num_of_messages + msgs.length);
                    }
                });
            }
            check_for_new_messages(0);
        });
```

And the server side code:

```
var http = require("http"), fs = require("fs"), url = require('url');

http.createServer(function (request, response) {
   var parameters = url.parse(request.url, true).query;
   var num_of_messages = parseInt(parameters.num_of_messages);
   check_for_new_messages(new Date(), num_of_messages, request, response);
}).listen(80);

function check_for_new_messages(startingTime, num_of_messages, request, response) {
var date = new Date();
if (date - startingTime >= 60000) {
    response.writeHead(200, {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
    });
    response.write('{no_new_messages: true}', 'utf8');
    response.end();
    return false;
}

var mongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
mongoClient.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/test", function (err, db) {
    var c = db.collection('message');
    c.count(function (err, count) {
        if (count > num_of_messages) {
            c.find({_id: {$gt: num_of_messages}}).toArray(function (err, items) {
                var str_items = JSON.stringify(items);
                response.writeHead(200, {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
                });
                response.write(str_items, 'utf8');
                response.end();
                return false;
            });
        }
    });
});

setTimeout(function () {
    check_for_new_messages(startingTime, num_of_messages, request, response)
}, 10000);
```

}

Thank you for your time.

Comment: running that function in a setTimeout outside doesn't make much sense, it'l get re-ran regardless of whether or not the response was ended. If the response ends, you don't want to start the function up again, instead, you wait for the client to initiate a new long-poll.

Comment: but setTimeout waits till it end execution before running again doesn't it? I believe setInteval does what you say but I may be wrong. What changes would you do?